# RestyGWT vs RequestFactory

Tags: performance, json, gwt, rpc, requestfactory

I'm thinking on migrating my current service layer based on GWT-RPC to something else. It is about 10 service interfaces with 5 methods each, and involving about 20 different domain entities, so you have an idea of the amount of work that would require to change the whole thing, which obviously I would like to minimize. I'm also using Gilead and a Guice based centralized Servlet to handle all the RPC requests.

The main reasons for the change are:

- TypeSerializers are consuming the most big part of the size of the app code.
- Serialization/deserialization on client side is SLOW specially on dev mode, which seems to be a common fact with GWT-RPC.
- Obviously I would like to minimize the on-wire payload, but is not a hard requirement.

The options that I'm thinking about are:

- RequestFactory, which is promoted as a faster beast. But I'm afraid that it would be a lot of work to replace all references in client code of domain objects to their proxy counterparts, and also I'm lazy to actually build all the the proxies.
- A full JSON/REST approach using RestyGWT, which looks like it would let me still use the domain objects, but I'm afraid that it would end up with an even slower deserialization? I'm not based on any fact, but couldn't find any kind of benchmark. It is just an impression.

I really would like to get suggestions.

Thanks!

Comment: Another thing to think about is that the full JSON/REST approach allows other clients to interact with your server more easily.

Comment: That is true, and is a point in favor of JSON/REST. But I care more about performance for now. Also I'm planing to develop mobile clients with GWT too so until I go native which is far away in the future, I'm fine with a service layer that only works with GWT.

Comment: Have you considered using GWT Overlay Types? They come with a very low deserialization cost (almost by definition).

Comment: @Hbf yes, but doing so I should create separated model/domain objects for my client code than for my server code, as they must extend JavascriptObject. One of the points of using RestyGWT would be keep using the same object for both sides, as both code bases are expecting to carry and work with those objects.

Comment: @triforce: I see, that makes sense. – In some projects I actually found myself using DTO's much more often than sending the actual objects. To keep the maintaining effort low, I looked into generating DTO's and Action/Result classes automatically at compile time. This worked quite well for me: static typing to catch errors, no boilerplate-code writing for me. This here is an approach: http://code.google.com/p/gwt-platform/wiki/BoilerplateGeneration#Generate_Action_and_Result but I found it to not be flexible enough and started writing my own.

Comment: If you are looking for performances and considering using RestyGWT you should definitly think about creating some specific DTOs. Because you do not want to send all your model to your client. Depending on your use case, you will maybe need only half of the information contained inside your model, so sending the whole object will be inefficient. It will faster serialisation/deserialisation.

Plus in term of layering your application it is a good thing to differentiate your model, and what you expose to your client(s).

Answer (score 1):

Although we are currently working with RequestFactory, I'm recommending REST.
These are the 3 main reasons why:

1. client and server implementations don't have to be dependent (if you ever plan on native apps for a non android device than forget about requestfactory).
2. new api changes in requestfactory break old client code (this has devastating results on production)
3. the REST eco system and communities are larger and it is easier to tackle issues in code, and allow other apps to communicate with yours in the future.